# What type of statistical test should I use for this specific example?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, regression-analysis

I am doing a research project analyzing COVID-19 Cases and its effect on unemployment rates within a country. So, for example, I have the percentage of the population that have COVID-19 in a country for 15 months. I also have another data set of the unemployment rates for the same 15 months as the other data set. I can visually see a trend in the sense that when covid cases rise, so do unemployment rates and vice versa. However, I am finding it particularly hard being able to find an appropriate statistical test for this, to confirm whether there is a correlation between these two variables.

Please give me any insightful advice. If you need more clarification than what was given I will be more than happy to share.

Thank you.

Comment: You can always compute the sample correlation. Correlation in itself may not always be meaningful. Do you want to look at whether covid cases forecast unemployment rates, for instance? If so, a Granger causality  test may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality

Comment: Not exactly, I want to look at whether there is a correlation between the two data sets. However, I cannot find the appropriate statistical test for this. Keep in mind, that these data sets are represented as separate lines on a graph.

Comment: Not sure I follow though; if you just want to compute correlation, why not treat it as a single data set with bivariate data, "x" being covid cases in a month, and "y" being unemployment rates in the same month? Of course, the month itself then doesn't matter in this calculation.